# Execute a task on completion of ParallelFlux without executing sequential (introduce a side affect)

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a `ParallelFlux`, want to execute a side effect action when all the components in all the rails are consumed. I was trying to use `.then()`.

But unable to understand how to use it.

Can anybody share its usage or a way to execute a side affect after all the elements go through OnError,OnComplete across rails.

Indicative code :

> RunTransformation provides a Parallel Flux in transformation,
>
> OnCompletion mark record as completed in a separate registry.
>
> RunAction does some action for each transformed record (independent of the other).
>
> RunError handles error.

Here I want to run RunCompletion only on final completion, but have to do sequential though consumers can be done in parallel.

```
   Mono.just(record)
       .flatMap(RunTransformation::tranformParallel)   //gives back ParallelFlux running on Schedulers.random()
       .sequential()
       .doOnTerminate(OnCompletion::markRecordProcessed)
       .subscribe(
            RunAction::execute, 
            RunError::handleError);
```

Comment: What is your issue with sequential?

Comment: the consumers RunAction.execute could have run in parallel but now it needs to run sequentially.

Comment: How can it run in parallel if you need everything to have completed before running it? And if it doesn't need everything you can just run onComplete without sequential. You need to provide an MRE because what your saying doesn't make any sense.

Comment: RunAction.execute()  can run in parallel. On completion if I receive a signal that the processing of all the rails is complete, then want to mark the original record as processed in a registry. Hope i am making sense now.

Comment: To give a background, I am consuming a kafka message and executing multiple tasks (RunAction.execute()) (which are not linked to each other) after all the processing completes it need to send a manual acknowledgement to kafka. In case the  sequential is not added, it will send as many manual acknowledgements as the parallel rails.if the sequential is added it will execute RunAction.execute() multiple times. Will check if I can make an MRE for this.

Comment: Just use `doOnSuccess`

Comment: @ThomasAndolf: My understanding is doOnTerminate will do for Success and Failure. Does doOnSuccess execute once in a ParallelFlux scenario or the number of rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using .then() as follows.

```
Mono.just(record)
        .flatMap(RunTransformation::tranformParallel)   //gives back ParallelFlux running on Schedulers.random()
        .doOnNext(RunAction::execute)
        .doOnError(RunError::handleError)
        .then()
        .doOnTerminate(() -> {System.out.println("all rails completed");})
        .subscribe();
```

Comment: Depends on where you want to execute the side effect. If executed in main thread, then definitely main thread would be required to block

Comment: Number of parallel is not known, so no luck there. I thought ParallelFlux has a .then(). But unable to find any implementation.

Comment: Yes , using .then() you can do. Edited the answer with then(), Hope it works.

Comment: edited the answer to match the solution that worked  Removed commented Sequential and additional doOnTerminate()

Answer (score 1):

taken from the documentation

> If, once you process your sequence in parallel, you want to revert back to a “normal” Flux and apply the rest of the operator chain in a sequential manner, you can use the sequential() method on ParallelFlux.

i think `doOnComplete` is what you are looking for.

```
Flux.range(1, 10)
        .parallel(3)
        .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " -> " + i))
        .sequential()
        .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("All parallel work is done"))
        .subscribe()
```

This produces the output:

```
parallel-1 -> 1
parallel-2 -> 2
parallel-3 -> 3
parallel-2 -> 5
parallel-3 -> 6
parallel-1 -> 4
parallel-1 -> 7
parallel-2 -> 8
parallel-3 -> 9
parallel-1 -> 10
All parallel work is done
```

[Reactor documentation on parallel flux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-parallelizing-parralelflux)